# Reading current time from a czml file

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

I have to read the current time (clock) from a czml file and pass to a variable, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

```
let czml = 'data/gps.czml'
viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml)).then(function(ds) {
 viewer.trackedEntity = ds.entities.getById('path');
 viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = true;
});
```

Comment: Are you also loading the data source, as shown in your sample code?  If so, the clock is already populated with the info you need, it's just `viewer.clock.currentTime` after the dataSource has loaded and before animation begins.

Comment: Yeh it works. It's simple but i found pretty hard to find examples on the web beside sandcastle. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, i can read the current time value but it is static, how do i get it to update the value each second?